# Rotate and Show, strange error message

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, rotation

The following code works, but produces an error message that I do not understand.
The message reads:
"An improperly formatted option head (Rotate) was encountered while reading a Graphics3DBox. The head of the option must be Rule or RuleDelayed."

Can somebody explain?

```
Manipulate[
 Rotate[#, {{1, 0, 0}, {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}}] & /@
  Show[
   Graphics3D[Sphere[]]
   , Plot3D[{x y, x^2, y^x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
   ]
 , {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: You can't do a 3D Rotate outside of the Graphics3D like this. Maybe you should manipulate the `ViewVector` of the `Show` instead.

Comment: Try this: `Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], 
  Plot3D[{x y, x^2, y^x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], 
  ViewVector -> 5*{Cos[-p], Sin[-p], 1}, Boxed -> False], {p, 0, 
  2 Pi}]`

Comment: maybe `Manipulate[Show[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], 
  MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#,  RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 0}, {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}}]] &, 
   Plot3D[{x y, x^2, y^x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {1, 2}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {p, 0, 2 Pi}]`?

Answer (score 1):

The rotation is equivalence to rotation around the line `line={0,0,1}`, we use `GeometricTransformation` companion with `RotationMatrix`

Since the head of `Plot3D` is `Graphics3D`,we use `@@` to replace the head.

```
Manipulate[
 line = {0, 0, 1};
 Show[Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[#, 
      RotationMatrix[p, line]] & @@ (Plot3D[{x y, x^2, y^x}, {x, -1, 
       1}, {y, -1, 1}, ClippingStyle -> None, Mesh -> None])],
  Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[Sphere[], RotationMatrix[p, line]]]], {p, 
  0.1, 2 Pi}]
```

Here we replace the `Sphere[]` with `Cuboid[]` and export a gif.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the expression onto which you are mapping the [`Rotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html)

```
show = Show[
   Graphics3D[Sphere[]],
   Plot3D[{x y, x^2, y^x},
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]];
```

While it has `Length` 2

```
Length@show

(* 2 *)
```

all of the graphics are in the first part

```
show[[1]]
```

[image]

and the second part is an empty list of options since no options were added to the `Show`

```
show[[2]]

(* {} *)
```

You want the `Rotate` used on the first part only since the second part will be interpreted as an option

```
Manipulate[MapAt[Rotate[#, {{1, 0, 0}, {Cos[p], Sin[p], 0}}] &,
  Show[
   Graphics3D[Sphere[]],
   Plot3D[{x y, x^2, y^x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    ClippingStyle -> None]],
  1],
 {{p, 3}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much.